# validar dos contraseñas y cancelar accion

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**Buenas**, tengo un formulario donde me piden que valide dos contraseñas y que si no son iguales que cancele el guardado en la base de datos, como puedo lograr eso ?  muchas gracias

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a edit para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: ¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?. También puede serte de interés realizar el recorrido y leer Cómo preguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes obtener el texto de cada campo y compararlo del siguiente modo:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.txtContraseña1.Text.Equals(this.txtContraseña2.Text)) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Son iguales, entonces las voy a guardar.");
                //Codigo para guardar...
            }
            else{
                MessageBox.Show("Son distintas, entonces NO las voy a guardar.");
                //Acciones correspondientes...
            }
        }
```

La comparación la hago con [Equals Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2). Pero tranquilamente lo puedes hacer así:

```
if (this.txtContraseña1.Text == this.txtContraseña2.Text)
```

Por favor lee [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic) y [Cómo preguntar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Saludos!

Comment: se te agradece el apoyo, pero preguntas que no muestran el mas minimo intento no se deben responder, ayudanos a mantener la calidad del sitio

Comment: Tienes razón @shadow, uno trata de ayudar pero luego no hacen el mínimo esfuerzo!